# C# How to use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery with abstract/derived classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, my situation is that I'm using EF6 and a Component table using the table per hierarchy pattern. I have an abstract Component class and a few classes that inherit it, such as FirstNameComponent.

The call looks something like this:

```
var sql = "Select * from Components";
var components = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Component>(sql).ToList();
```

*In this case, I must use `SqlQuery` off either `DbContext` or `DbSet`.*

As you'd expect, this queries out all the components in the table and tries to map them to the Component class, but since it's abstract, an exception is thrown.

Is there a way to use a custom model binder or something with the discriminator column on the table to tell the SqlQuery call which classes to use for each Component? Or maybe a different way to serialize/deserialize the rows into the Component classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a discriminator property inside your abstract class (basically the name of the column you want as the discriminator, as a string)

Say, you have the `Component` class as an abstract class and the `FirstNameComponent` is inheriting that.

So, You would like your `Component` class to look something like -

```
public abstract class Component
{
    public const string Discriminator = "ComponentType";

    // Other properties/methods
}
```

Now, your `FirstNameComponent` class would look like -

```
public class FirstNameComponent : Component
{
    public const string TypeOfComponent = nameof(FirstNameComponent);

    public override string ComponentType // your discriminator column
    {
        get
        {
            return TypeOfComponent;
        }
    }
    // Other properties/methods
}
```

and use this property when building your model using fluent API inside your context..

```
public class ComponentContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FirstNameComponent> FirstNameComponents { get; set; }

    // Other mappings 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Component>()
            .Map<FirstNameComponent>(
                configuration =>
                configuration.Requires(Component.Discriminator).HasValue(FirstNameComponent.TypeOfComponent))
    }
}
```

Accordingly, your query would be something like -

```
var components = ComponentContext.Components.OfType<FirstNameComponent>();
```

or even -

```
var components = ComponentContext.Components.Where(c => c is FirstNameComponent).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at your updated question, here is how you can restructure your query to fetch a particular type of `Component` -

```
string sqlQuery = @"Select * from Components Where ComponentType = @componentType";
string componentType = nameof(FirstNameComponent); //Can be made more dynamic

// Pass the type of component you need to cast to as a parameter
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@componentType", componentType);

var components = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<FirstNameComponent>(sqlQuery, parameter);
```

This should give you the desired result.

**UPDATE 2**

So, after some more research on this, I found [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) blog which talks about Polymorphic queries using both Linq to Entities and EntitySQL.

Based on the reference, here is another way you could try out to get all the `Components` -

```
string sqlQuery = @"SELECT VALUE c FROM Components AS c";
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ComponentContext).ObjectContext;
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<Component> objectQuery = objectContext.CreateQuery<Component>(sqlQuery);
List<Component> components = objectQuery.ToList<Component>();
```

And once you have all the `Components`, you could just filter out the desired types using a simple `Where` clause on the `ComponentType` field -

```
var firstNameComponents = components.Where(c => c.ComponentType == nameof(FirstNameComponent)).ToList();
```

Comment: So, in this case I need to use `SqlQuery` either off `DbContext.Database` or `DbSet` because I need to use custom sql to get the components out. Can you provide a solution that works with both the mapping you laid out and `SqlQuery`?

Comment: @KevDev424 - Look at my updated answer...As I have mentioned, you can write a more dynamic program to resolve the type of `component` at run time...

Comment: That looks good, but what if I don't know the types when making the query and want to rely on the Context mapping on its own like it does by default? I want to get all the components using custom sql and have the abstract to concrete Component mappings work automatically. I might be asking for too much.

Comment: hmmm...I see your point...but since you cannot instantiate an abstract class, there is no __straight forward__ way of getting all the `components` at one go and then cast to the deriving types. That leaves you two options (there might still more be though..) -  change your approach so that you know before querying the derived type you need to cast to __OR__ use automapper such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973258/automapper-and-base-types (they haven't used SqlQuery though)

Comment: I'll make this as the answer as I think it's the closest thing I could do. I changed my approach though, making one custom query for the Component ids, then a second query using the DbSet and a where clause with the ids to get the custom mapping for each derived class. I don't think there's a good way to do this in one custom query.

Comment: @KevDev424 - thanks, see my update, though it is not using exactly __SqlQuery off either DbContext or DbSet__, but it gives you the flexibility of customizing your query...